# What version of Sitecore JavaScript Rendering SDK CLI Tools is compatible with Node version 16

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk

Need to integrate `sitecore-jss-cli` into `ReactJS` application. The node version currently used is `Node 16.13.0`. The latest `JSS` cli version `21.6.4` is not compatible with this node version. what version of CLI will be compatible?

Comment: More importantly - what version of Sitecore XM/XP are you using?

Comment: I'd guess maybe JSS 13 or so. I think you'd have to try and see.

Comment: The problem here is that the JSS version is tied to the Sitecore XM/XP version. You can't just decide to use JSS 13 if you are using XM/XP 10.3.x. You need to update your node version to match what you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to consider revisiting your approach and opt for the most recent and stable/actively supported version of Node, which is `Node 20`, especially if you intend to utilize the latest Sitecore JSS.

Alternatively, if you prefer to stick with Node 16, then `Sitecore JSS 19 or 20` would be more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can _only_ use JSS 19 or 20 if you are on XM/XP 10.2. If you are on on 10.3, you _must_ use JSS 21

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the dependencies which are registered in package.json and they were registered with what versions, So there can be two scenario

1. If you are starting fresh, latest version of sitecore, you can use the latest and greatest completable version of node
2. If you are working on already existing project you will need to follow specific version for which the package were installed

What you can try is you can have different version of node like "v16.7.0", "v18.0.0" and you can switch between versions from terminal to see which one works for you by doing

***nvm use "16.7.0"*** and doing "npm run build"

**NOTE**: *Always make sure to delete "node_modules" and package.lock.json file before doing build else it will not give you correct results*